# why we have to use (rear+1)%capacity in enqueue in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

```
  void enqueue( int item)
{
    if (is Full(this))
        return;
    this.rear = (this.rear + 1)%this.capacity;
    this.array[this.rear] = item;
    this.size = this.size + 1;
    System.out.println(item+ " enqueued to queue");
}
```

question is- why we have to do this this.rear = (this.rear + 1)%this.capacity; while making an enqueue function in java?

Comment: It is incrementing `rear` but wrapping around so it stays within the bounds of the array. If `this.rear` is equal to `this.capacity-1` (the end of the array), then `(this.rear+1)%this.capacity` will evaluate to zero (the beginning of the array).

Answer (score 1):

In single ended queue there's no such concept. I will assume you're dealing with `Circular Queue`. `this.rear = (this.rear + 1)%this.capacity;` is used to point the rear to the `rear+1'th` index. (especially when rear has reached the `(n-1)th` position.)

***e.g.***: `array[10]` i.e. `capacity = 10` and `rear is at arr[9]` and `arr[0..x] (where x<=(n-1))` is empty

In this situation queue should allow insertion as there's still empty space in array. For this apply the formula

1. When `rear = 9`

   `this.rear = (this.rear + 1)%this.capacity;`

   i.e. `this.rear = (9 + 1)%10 = 0` i.e. insert at `0'th` index
2. Similarly when `when rear = 2`

   `this.rear = (2 + 1)%10 = 3`

and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's made to implement circular queue, i.e to return to beginning of the array every time rear or head counters reach the end of an array.

When rear counter is less than array's length, rear % length = rear.

When rear counter is equal to array's length, rear % length gives 0 and rear counter goes on the next lap.

Finally, when rear is greater than array's length, rear % length will return value less then array length and equal to rear - (array.length * number of passed circles).

So, by dividing rear on length, we get the remainder, which is next position for an element that we want to place at the end of the queue.